# Macros in "Word commands"

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, microsoft-word-2013

Recently, I created a macro and named it `TableProperties` and saved it. This macro will change the `AltText` in table properties of all the table in the document.

I opened a different document today and found that `AltText` in `TableProperties` is changed in all the tables in that document.

I checked the macros in that document and found `TableProperties` macro in `Word commands`. Delete button is disabled for all the macros in `Word commands`

Note: Macros are not present in any other options other than `Word commands`

Please let me know how to delete the macro from `Word commands`. I have attached the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

switch from Macros in : "**Word commands**" to "**All active Templates and Documents**"

this **TableProprieties** you found in "**Word commands**" is not a macro you have access to. You can not edit or delete it, it is a build-in Macro in Word.

You can copy it to a Document and use it there, but then you edit the version you have in the document. Use the selectbox called **Macros in** to switch to the macros of a document or to list all Macros "**All active Templates and Documents**"

Comment: thanks for your reply, but "All active Templates and Documents" does not have a macro, it is empty

Comment: TableProprieties is not a macro you can edit or delete, it is a build-in Macro in Word. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.table_properties%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: You are right, I searched all day but could not find an option to delete or edit it.. All the macros in "Word commands" are non-editable ? Please add this info to your answer, I'll mark it as answer